# Implement function overloading in typescript

Tags: function, typescript, overloading

I know that function overloading is not supported in typescript and javascript.

And I'm studying a detour method to work like this function overloading.

My case is as follows.

first:

The last ans first argument is fixed.

```
public A(arg1:number, arg2:number, argLast:any){

}

public A(arg1:number, arg2:number, arg3:Array<any>, argLast:any){

}
```

Second :

[image]

There is an indicator for whether the function is overloaded.

Of course, as in the above example, it is possible, but I have to create it through a new interface, so it does not fit in my case.

I have tried various function overloading methods.

I also implemented it through john resig blog.

(https://johnresig.com/blog/javascript-method-overloading/)

The code below is an example I made through the above blog.

```
function addMethod (object, name, fn) {
  var old = object[ name ]
  object[ name ] = function () {
    if (fn.length === arguments.length) {
      return fn.apply(this, arguments)
    } else if (typeof old === 'function') {
      return old.apply(this, arguments)
    }
  }
}

export class Users{
  find(...arg: any[]){
    Users.prototype['findOVF'](arg)
  }
}
addMethod(Users.prototype, 'findOVF', function () {
  console.log('ARG 0')
})
addMethod(Users.prototype, 'findOVF', function (name:string, age:number) {
  console.log('ARG 2')
})
addMethod(Users.prototype, 'findOVF', function (first_name:string, last_name:string,age:number) {
  console.log('ARG 3')
})

var users = new Users()
users.find() 
users.find('John',19) 
users.find('John', 'Resig', 19)
```

When I use this method, I call the function with the parameter (... arg).

I've tried to implement all the methods of the blog below.

(https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/08/18/function-overloads-in-typescript)

```
public A(arg1:number, arg2:number, argLast:any){

}

public A(arg1:number, arg2:number, arg3:Array<any>|null, argLast:any){

}
```

If I implement function overloading this way, I get an error every time I call the A function. It's not really function overloading.

But I have not found a way to implement these two elements at the same time.

I want to know if this is impossible with the typescript grammar or if there is any other possibility.

Thanks for seeing my awkward English.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what does not work. COuld you post a complete example with the code you would like to work but does not work or does not work as expected ?

Comment: ok. i`ll post right now. However, the writing will be very long. I hope you understand.

Comment: I tried to describe the method I tried. I have a question too ... I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create overloads in typescript but all the overloads have a single implementation and it's up to you to differentiate between them. The simplest solution, if your methods are all differentiated just by number of parameters is this:

```
class User { }
export class Users {
    find(): User;
    find(name: string, age: number): User;
    find(first_name: string, last_name: string, age: number): User
    find(...args: [any?, any?, any?]): User {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            return null as any;
        } else if (args.length == 1) {
            let [name, age, _]: [string?, number?, any?] = args;
            console.log(`${name}, ${age}`);
            return null as any;
        } else if (args.length == 2){
            let [first_name, last_name, age]: [string?, string?, number?] = args;
            console.log(`${first_name}, ${last_name}, ${age}`);
            return null as any;
        } else {
            throw "Not implemented";
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20User%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Users%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20find()%3A%20User%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20find(name%3A%20string%2C%20age%3A%20number)%3A%20User%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20find(first_name%3A%20string%2C%20last_name%3A%20string%2C%20age%3A%20number)%3A%20User%0D%0A%20%20%20%20find(...args%3A%20%5Bany%3F%2C%20any%3F%2C%20any%3F%5D)%3A%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(args.length%20%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(args.length%20%3D%3D%201)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20%5Bname%2C%20age%2C%20_%5D%3A%20%5Bstring%3F%2C%20number%3F%2C%20any%3F%5D%20%3D%20args%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60%24%7Bname%7D%2C%20%24%7Bage%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(args.length%20%3D%3D%202)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20%5Bfirst_name%2C%20last_name%2C%20age%5D%3A%20%5Bstring%3F%2C%20string%3F%2C%20number%3F%5D%20%3D%20args%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60%24%7Bfirst_name%7D%2C%20%24%7Blast_name%7D%2C%20%24%7Bage%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20%22Not%20implemented%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

The above solution preserves call site type safety, your solution does not since the argument to `find` is `any[]` in your example.

You could use a more automated approach by defining a function that will create an overloaded function form an array of functions but wather this extra complexity is worth it you be the judge.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

function overloads<TThis>(){
    return function<T extends Array<(this: TThis, ...args: any[]) => any>>(...fns: T): UnionToIntersection<T[number]> {
        return function (this: TThis, ...args: any[]) {
            for (var fn of fns) {
                if (fn.length === args.length) {
                    return fn.apply(this, args);
                }
            }
            throw "Not implemented";
        } as any
    }
}

class User { }
export class Users {
    member: string = "M"
    find = overloads<Users>()(
        function () {
            console.log('ARG 0');
            this.member // this is Users 
        },
        function (name: string, age: number) {
            console.log('ARG 2')
        },
        function (first_name: string, last_name: string, age: number) {
            console.log('ARG 3')
        }
    );
}

var users = new Users()
users.find('John', 19)
users.find('John', 'Resig', 19)
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20UnionToIntersection%3CU%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(U%20extends%20any%20%3F%20(k%3A%20U)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3A%20never)%20extends%20((k%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20overloads%3CTThis%3E()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%3CT%20extends%20Array%3C(this%3A%20TThis%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%3E%3E(...fns%3A%20T)%3A%20UnionToIntersection%3CT%5Bnumber%5D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(this%3A%20TThis%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20fn%20of%20fns)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(fn.length%20%3D%3D%3D%20args.length)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20fn.apply(this%2C%20args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20%22Not%20implemented%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20as%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20User%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Users%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20member%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22M%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20find%20%3D%20overloads%3CUsers%3E()(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('ARG%200')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.member%20%2F%2F%20this%20is%20Users%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20(name%3A%20string%2C%20age%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('ARG%202')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20(first_name%3A%20string%2C%20last_name%3A%20string%2C%20age%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('ARG%203')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20users%20%3D%20new%20Users()%0D%0Ausers.find('John'%2C%2019)%0D%0Ausers.find('John'%2C%20'Resig'%2C%2019)%20%0D%0A)

Or a version that assigns the function to the prototype not the instance:

```
export class Users {
    member: string = "M"
}

let find = overloads<Users>()(
    function () {
        console.log('ARG 0');
        this.member // this is Users 
    },
    function (name: string, age: number) {
        console.log('ARG 2')
    },
    function (first_name: string, last_name: string, age: number) {
        console.log('ARG 3')
    }
);
export interface Users {
    find: typeof find;
}
Users.prototype.find = find;
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20UnionToIntersection%3CU%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(U%20extends%20any%20%3F%20(k%3A%20U)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3A%20never)%20extends%20((k%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20overloads%3CTThis%3E()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%3CT%20extends%20Array%3C(this%3A%20TThis%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%3E%3E(...fns%3A%20T)%3A%20UnionToIntersection%3CT%5Bnumber%5D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(this%3A%20TThis%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20fn%20of%20fns)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(fn.length%20%3D%3D%3D%20args.length)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20fn.apply(this%2C%20args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20%22Not%20implemented%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20as%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Users%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20member%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22M%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20find%20%3D%20overloads%3CUsers%3E()(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('ARG%200')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.member%20%2F%2F%20this%20is%20Users%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20(name%3A%20string%2C%20age%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('ARG%202')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20(first_name%3A%20string%2C%20last_name%3A%20string%2C%20age%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('ARG%203')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Users%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20find%3A%20typeof%20find%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AUsers.prototype.find%20%3D%20find%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20users%20%3D%20new%20Users()%0D%0Ausers.find('John'%2C%2019)%0D%0Ausers.find('John'%2C%20'Resig'%2C%2019)%20)

Comment: thank you your kindly answer!. but i have some error : rest parameter must be of an array type. and JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments.

Comment: @naiad what version of typescript are you using, the above code works for 3.0

Comment: @naiad the first version will work for any version of typescript, and is the simplest one to understand, I would go with that one for simple overloads

Comment: my IDE is visual studio code and when i write "tsc -v" command : Version 3.0.1

Comment: @naiad added playground links to all examples, they all work without error and should work in your IDE as well.

Comment: @naiad But this error `rest parameter must be of an array type.` suggests that at least your IDE is not using 3.0. You can see in the right corner of VSCode the version of TS being used.

Comment: i really thank appreciate you help. thank you. i think that remain problem from IDE setting. that was my homework.

Comment: ouch. could you plz help me? i use second example. and i learn about 'type' keyword is aka type level function. but. if i use this keyword with angular service. type keyword is unexpect token and error occur.

Comment: @naiad not sure I understand your question... Why do you need `type` inside an angular  service ? The only `type` I use is `UnionToIntersection` and that needs to be defined once outside of any service